# Importing Ethereum Account Private Key and Using on Different Servers

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, import, export

Let's suppose i have a wallet on one remote server, `R-1`. Is it possible to get the private key of that wallet/account and use it on different remote server `R-2`? I know, i can copy/paste files under `keystore` of a specific wallet from `R-1` server to `R-2` server but I am more interested in getting a private key, which when exporting from `CLI` on `R-2` will import my account without copying/pasting. As per my understanding, `Ethereum` must have my account's information, if yes, then how can use that available information to use my wallet on different server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one pair public and private key to do blockchain movements from many different servers or wallet apps at the same time. Your address history is not stored in some back-end server or in the server of the wallet application you use on your mobile phone, but on the blockchain, because it's peer to peer network. Every running node have copy of what you did in the past and that's the point of the decentralization. People get easily confused that if they remove the wallet app they use on their phones they will lose their crypto funds - no, these apps are just reading the funds from the blockchain network.